# Java FX Modular Application, Module not found (Java 11, Intellij)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, module, javafx-11

Hello I have a problem with my modular Java FX Application.

First of all I created a JavaFX Project with the Intellij Wizard.
I added the Java FX lib:

[image: Project Strucutre with JavaFX lib]

And the JavaFX modules get recognized. My module-info.java:

[image: module-info]

I also added the VM options:

[image: VM Options and Config]

But I always get this errormessage:

[image: Errormessage]

"Error occured during initialization of boot layer
 java.lang.module.FindException: Module HelloFX not found"

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you get the error:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
>
> java.lang.module.FindException: Module HelloFX not found

it means that the path to the module in question in `--module-path` is wrong and the module can't be found.

Check the output folder. Based on your first picture, the output of the `HelloFX` project goes to `out`, but your VM options you are setting the relative path to `mods`.

You can configure the compiler output from `IntelliJ -> File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Project Compile Output`.

On Windows by default, when you create a JavaFX project, IntelliJ points to `\path-to\HelloFX\out`.

Then you either modify that compile output path to `\path-to\HelloFX\mods`, or your VM arguments:

```
--module-path "\path-to\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\lib;out\production"
```