# JavaFX 11 doesn't work with JDK 11, intellij idea

Tags: java, javafx, java-11, javafx-11

Trying to get JavaFX 11 working.

1. Downloaded JavaFX 11
2. Created JavaFX project in IntelliJ IDEA
3. Run -> Edit configurations -> VM options -> --module-path="path-to-javafx/javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
4. Got an error:

   ```
   Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
   java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found

   Process finished with exit code 1
   ```

What should I do to make this work?

Comment: java11 does not include javafx, which you must now install separately.

Comment: Did you check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53447738/java-fx-modular-application-module-not-found-java-11-intellij)? Have you checked the docs for getting started with [JavaFX 11 and IntelliJ](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij)? Please explain what is different in your case from any of the mentioned samples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java FX Modular Application, Module not found (Java 11, Intellij)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53447738/java-fx-modular-application-module-not-found-java-11-intellij)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jose Pereda advised me to check JavaFX 11 and IntelliJ - https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij
It helped.