# Intellij JavaFX helloWorld Module not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I've followed the advice found at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51478675/error-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing-and-are-required-to-run-this-appli) and been able to get JavaFX playing nicely with Intellij on Linux. However, attempting to do the same on Windows 10 (adding the javafx sdk, setting the virtual machine options) has resulted in the following error when the default hello world program is run:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\java.exe" \
    --module-path C:/Users/user01/Downloads/openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk/lib \
    --add-modules=javafx.controls \
    --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics \
    --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED \
    "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=55783:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.3\bin" \
    -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
    -classpath C:\Users\user01\Source\Repos\CalendarToDO\out\production\CalendarToDO;C:\Users\user01\Downloads\openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\src.zip;C:\Users\user01\Downloads\openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx-swt.jar;C:\Users\user01\Downloads\openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.web.jar;C:\Users\user01\Downloads\openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\Users\user01\Downloads\openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.fxml.jar;C:\Users\user01\Downloads\openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.media.jar;C:\Users\user01\Downloads\openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.swing.jar;C:\Users\user01\Downloads\openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.controls.jar;C:\Users\user01\Downloads\openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.graphics.jar \
    sample.Main

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer: java.lang.module.FindException: \
    Module javafx.base not found

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Which is odd, as I can expanded the added lib and see the .jar for javafx.base:

[image: ProjectSetup]

Any help or experience others have had would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you try changing the module path to: `C:\Users\user01\Downloads\openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\lib`?

Comment: Just did, the same error message is displayed

Comment: Your module path is wrong, you are missing `\javafx-sdk-11.0.2`

Comment: You are an absolute lifesaver, should've verified the full path ages ago. Thank you immensely!

Comment: Glad that you solved it. This question was duplicated of this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53447738/java-fx-modular-application-module-not-found-java-11-intellij), by the way.