# Soap Webservice Client for JAVAFX Application

Tags: java, soap-client, webservice-client, javafx-11

I am trying to call the webservice for my application. If I call it in a sample project it is working perfectly fine. But when I merge it with My Java FX it is giving me so many errors. Web Service Client is auto generated using the Eclipse. I am trying to call the Methods only. Can Anyone help me?

```
Error: **Correction** I have edited it and I am using now JAVASE-15 and JVAFX-SDK 11.0.2
The package javax.xml.namespace is accessible from more than one module: java.xml, jaxrpc


Correction Update 2: I have removed Java.xml dependencies and module-info file as well.
but the new error is this

**Error: Could not find or load main class gload.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application**

and IF I keep the module info file it shows:
**Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.graphics not found, required by gload**
```

Model:

```
package gload.model;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.PE_PPER_MyPdmWebServiceClient_Data.CustomerItem;
import org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.PE_PPER_MyPdmWebServiceClient_Data.Result;
import org.tempuri.IService;
import org.tempuri.ServiceLocator;

public class PdmData 
 {
   public String scode;
   public boolean state = false;

   
   
   public static String CdfFile;
    
    public static String pdflocation;
    
    public static String Custom_Ci;

    public static String Generic_Ci;
    
    public static String Mp_ref;
    
    public static String Interface;
    
    public static String Comments;
    
    public static String PersoAppli;
    
    public static String Code;
    public static String Revision;
    public static String Customer_Name;
    public static String Customer_reference;
    
    
    public static String getCode() {
        return Code;
    }

    public static void setCode(String code) {
        Code = code;
    }

    public static String getRevision() {
        return Revision;
    }

    public static void setRevision(String revision) {
        Revision = revision;
    }

    public static String getCustomer_Name() {
        return Customer_Name;
    }

    public static void setCustomer_Name(String customer_Name) {
        Customer_Name = customer_Name;
    }

    public static String getCustomer_reference() {
        return Customer_reference;
    }

    public static void setCustomer_reference(String customer_reference) {
        Customer_reference = customer_reference;
    }

    public static String getPersoAppli() {
        return PersoAppli;
    }

    public static void setPersoAppli(String persoAppli) {
        PersoAppli = persoAppli;
    }



    public static String getGeneric_Ci() {
        return Generic_Ci;
    }

    public static void setGeneric_Ci(String generic_Ci) {
        Generic_Ci = generic_Ci;
    }
   
      
    public static String getCdfFile() {
        return CdfFile;
    }

    public static void setCdfFile(String cdfFile) {
        CdfFile = cdfFile;
    }

    public static String getPdflocation() {
        return pdflocation;
    }

    public static void setPdflocation(String pdflocation) {
        PdmData.pdflocation = pdflocation;
    }


   
   public String Cdffile(String reference) {
       ServiceLocator locator = new ServiceLocator(); -------->Web Service Locator and call
        try {
            IService basicHttpBinding_IService = locator.getBasicHttpBinding_IService();
            Result result = basicHttpBinding_IService.getFilebyDcode(reference);
            
            //To download the files
            String link = result.getLocation();
            System.out.println(link);
           File out = new File("C:\\TempDownload\\" + reference +".zip");  //Creating a zip file to store the contents of download file
           new Thread(new Download(link,out)).start();
           //To Unzip the file
            Path source = Paths.get("C:\\TempDownload\\" + reference +".zip");
            Path target = Paths.get("C:\\TempDownload\\Unzip");

                try {

                    unzipFolder(source, target);
                    System.out.println("Done");

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //Creating a File object for directory
                File directoryPath = new File("C:\\TempDownload\\Unzip\\Pre Ppc" + reference + "A_Released");
                //List of all files and directories
                String[] contents = directoryPath.list();
                System.out.println("List of files and directories in the specified directory:");
                FilenameFilter pdffilter = new FilenameFilter() {
                    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                        String lowercaseName = name.toLowerCase();
                        if (lowercaseName.endsWith(".pdf")) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                };
                     String[] contents1 = directoryPath.list(pdffilter);
                     for(String fileName : contents1) {
                         System.out.println(fileName);
                         setCdfFile(fileName);
                         setPdflocation(directoryPath.toString());
                      }
                   //To extract the Data From PDF

                        File file = new File(getPdflocation() + "\\" + getCdfFile());
                        //FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

                        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
                        PDFTextStripper pdfReader = new PDFTextStripper();
                        String docText = pdfReader.getText(document);
                        System.out.println(docText);

                        document.close();
                        
                        //To extract details from document 
                        String CI_Ref = "CI Ref";
                        
                        int pos ;
                        pos = docText.indexOf(CI_Ref);
                        setGeneric_Ci(docText.substring(pos+7 , pos+15));
                        System.out.println("Generic CI: " + getGeneric_Ci());

                        //To get Details of CI
                        CustomerItem customerItem = basicHttpBinding_IService.getCiDetails(getGeneric_Ci());
                        setPersoAppli(customerItem.getPersoAppli());
                        setCode(customerItem.getCode());
                        setRevision(customerItem.getRevision());
                        setCustomer_Name(customerItem.getCustomerName());
                        setCustomer_reference(customerItem.getCustomerReference());

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to reach Service : " +  e.getMessage());
        }
    
        return getPersoAppli();
   }
```

Module info file

```
module gload {

    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires java.desktop;

    requires java.rmi;
    requires java.base;
    requires axis;
    requires jaxrpc;
    requires org.apache.pdfbox;


    opens gload;
    opens gload.views.main;
    opens gload.utils;
    opens gload.model;
    opens gload.controllers;
    opens org.tempuri;
    opens org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.PE_PPER_MyPdmWebServiceClient_Data;
}
```

and IF I keep Jaxrpc in classpath instead of module path I get error like this Description
**The type javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files**

Comment: The error is telling you that Java cannot find the [org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal.html) class. I find that strange given it's part of the standard library...

Comment: The `org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal` class was only added to the standard java libraries in Java 9 and this question is tagged `javafx-8`, so perhaps the questioner is using Java 8 rather than a later version of Java.

Comment: Not related to the question, but I don't recommend using `JOptionPane` (or other Swing or AWT classes) in a JavaFX application when JavaFX has in-built dialogs you can use instead.

Comment: @jewelsea I must have added this when I was running it separately and forgot to remove. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @jewelsea I have edited the question, If you can help me out now.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this won't really be an answer, more pointers to related issues and potential approaches to come up with solutions.  But I'll post it as an answer as it is likely better to do that than lots of comments.

Unfortunately, you have multiple errors and issues, so I'll try to deal with some of them seperately.

---

According to:

- [Java FX Modular Application, Module not found (Java 11, Intellij)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53447738/java-fx-modular-application-module-not-found-java-11-intellij/53448261#53448261)

The error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: 
Module X not found, required by Y
```

can occur when `--module-path` is wrong and the module can't be found. Probably, that is at least one of your issues. The linked answer is for Idea and I don't use Eclipse, so I don't know how to resolve the issue in Eclipse, but perhaps you could do some research to find out.

---

Regarding:

```
The package javax.xml.namespace is accessible from more than one module
```

there is some info on what is going on here:

- [Eclipse is confused by imports ("accessible from more than one module")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571046/eclipse-is-confused-by-imports-accessible-from-more-than-one-module).

This fix appears tricky to me. Please review the linked questions and solutions. It looks like either you need to either

1. Forego Java 9+ modularity OR
2. Manage your dependencies to not include the violating transitive dependency OR
3. Change to a library that doesn't rely on the broken library (probably the preferred solution in this case).

The broken library causing this issue is likely the version of `jaxrpc` you are using.  My guess is that some of the relevant XML libraries were only added to standard Java in Java 9, but the jaxrpc library you are using was developed prior to that. So, jaxrpc either includes the XML libraries in its classes or makes use of a transitive library that does the same.  This causes a conflict because the XML libraries can only be included once in the project.

---

Further info on your issues is in this answer:

- [Eclipse can't find XML related classes after switching build path to JDK 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094274/eclipse-cant-find-xml-related-classes-after-switching-build-path-to-jdk-10/53824670#53824670)

The info is so ugly . . . you could read the answer, it may either help or discourage you.

---

**Some things you could do to help resolve the situation**

What should be done about this is kind of tricky and will depend on your skill level and how or if you can solve it.  I'll offer up some advice on some things you could do, but there are other options.  You know your application better than I so you may be able to come up with better solutions for your application.

I'd advise separating these things out, just as a way of troubleshooting, get a project which works with all of the JavaFX components and one which works with all of the SOAP components and make sure they build and do what you want. Then try to combine the two projects either by integrating them into one project or running them in separate VMs with communication between the two (e.g. via an added REST API, though that is a much more complicated solution, so think hard about that before attempting it).

Also, upgrade to the latest version of JavaFX. I don't think it will fix your issue, but it can't hurt and it is possible some refinements in recent JavaFX versions may have done some things which might help ease some of your issues (though not all of them, as some of your issues stem from jaxrpc usage in a modular project, which is unrelated to JavaFX).

Also, and probably more importantly, consider using a different SOAP client framework that interacts better with modular Java 9+ than the broken implementation that jaxrpc appears to have.

In terms of whether you should make your application modular or not (include a module-info or not), I don't really know the best approach for you.  Certainly, whichever way you choose you will run into issues.  But, the issues and how to resolve them will be different depending on the chosen solution path (as I guess you have already discovered during the course of your investigation for the question).

If necessary, isolate the issues down to single separate issues.  If you need help in resolving each separate issue post new questions that feature [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code to replicate the issue.  Mind if you do so, that the code is absolutely minimal and also complete so that it replicates and asks about only one issue, not a combination of more than one and that the questions are appropriate tagged - e.g. if the question is about jaxrpc and modularity it should include jaxrpc and modular tags and no JavaFX code or tags (and vice versa) and certainly on pdf code or dependencies anywhere if that isn't part of the problem.